# Dropdown filter in custom posts

Tags: filters, dropdown

This is my snippet for drop-down filter in custom posts types:

```
<?php        
        function blog_restrict_manage_posts() {
        global $typenow;
        $taxonomy = 'blog'; // Change this
        if( $typenow != "page" && $typenow != "post" ){
            $filters = array($taxonomy);
            foreach ($filters as $tax_slug) {
                $tax_obj = get_taxonomy($tax_slug);
                $tax_name = $tax_obj->labels->name;
                $terms = get_terms($tax_slug);
                echo "<select name='$tax_slug' id='$tax_slug' class='postform'>";
                echo "<option value=''>Wszystkie $tax_name</option>";
                foreach ($terms as $term) { 
                    $label = (isset($_GET[$tax_slug])) ? $_GET[$tax_slug] : ''; // Fix
                    echo '<option value='. $term->slug, $label == $term->slug ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>' . $term->name .' (' . $term->count .')</option>';
                }
                echo "</select>";
            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'blog_restrict_manage_posts' );
?>
```

But there is one small issue - I have a two custom posts: 'x' and 'y'. And I have this drop-down menu filter. But filter for 'x' is visible in custom posts 'y' admin page and vice versa. So, every drop-downs are visible in every custom posts admin pages...

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your question? What is the issue? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I do not know how to fix it, even to start :D My issue is: I have a two custom posts: 'x' and 'y'. And I have this dropdown menu filter. But filter for 'x' is visible in custom posts 'y' admin page and vice versa. So, every dropdowns are visible in every custom posts admin pages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using this hook, your function receives two parameters, onde of them is the slug of the current post_type;

```
<?php
function my_post_type_filter($post_type) {

  $post_slug = $post_type; 

  if( $post_slug == 'the_post_type_slug') {
    // Do something
  }
}


add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'my_post_type_filter' );

?>
```

To learn more about this hook check the [Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/restrict_manage_posts/).